# find list value in datatable and update in datatable and other column

Tags: c#

I have a list which i would like to compare with my Data table. The data table has 2 columns and I need to compare column 1 of the data table with the list, if there are any matches, i need to update data table an other column of same data table with found number. how can i do this.

this is my table i need to update tag column from find list value in data table please help

[image]

Comment: This question is missing the code you have so far.. it sounds like you want to do "for each DataRow in table, if list contains row.somecolumn set row.othercolumn equal to row.somecolumn" ... ?

Comment: yes, i need to update by matching list item to data table item if value found then insert found value in same data table another column

Answer (score 0):

```
    Please use below code snippet to solve your problem. 
    
     List<int> lstItem = new List<int>();
                lstItem.Add(1);
                lstItem.Add(2);
                lstItem.Add(3);
                lstItem.Add(15);
                lstItem.Add(4);
                lstItem.Add(5);
                DataTable dtItems = new DataTable();
                dtItems.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("frm", typeof(int)));
                dtItems.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("quality", typeof(decimal)));
                dtItems.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("tag", typeof(int)));
                DataRow drnNewRow = dtItems.NewRow();
                drnNewRow["frm"] = 1;
                drnNewRow["quality"] = 0.4;
                dtItems.Rows.Add(drnNewRow);
                drnNewRow = dtItems.NewRow();
                drnNewRow["frm"] = 2;
                drnNewRow["quality"] = 0.5;
                dtItems.Rows.Add(drnNewRow);
                drnNewRow = dtItems.NewRow();
                drnNewRow["frm"] = 3;
                drnNewRow["quality"] = 0.6;
                dtItems.Rows.Add(drnNewRow);
                drnNewRow = dtItems.NewRow();
                drnNewRow["frm"] = 4;
                drnNewRow["quality"] = 0.7;
                dtItems.Rows.Add(drnNewRow);
                drnNewRow = dtItems.NewRow();
                drnNewRow["frm"] = 5;
                drnNewRow["quality"] = 0.8;
                dtItems.Rows.Add(drnNewRow);
                dtItems.AcceptChanges();
                foreach(var item in lstItem)
                {
                   DataRow[] drFound= dtItems.Select("frm=" + item);
                    if(drFound.Length>0)
                    {
                        drFound[0]["tag"]=item;
                    }
                }
                dtItems.AcceptChanges();

Output :
1- 0.4 -1
2- 0.5 -2
3- 0.6 -3
4- 0.7 -4
5- 0.8 -5
```

Comment: DataRow[] drFound= dtItems.Select("frm=" + item); it is not working because my data is dublicate in nature both list and datatable

Comment: Muhammad Sajid, you can use distinct like
DataView view = new DataView(dtItems);
DataTable distinctValues = view.ToTable(true, "Column1", "Column2" ...);

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use a HashSet than a List for this. You can easily convert a List to a HashSet by calling ToHashSet on it

If your table is an int and your array is an int:

```
var hs = (new List{1,2,3,4,5}).ToHashSet();

foreach(DataRow ro in dataTable.Rows){
  if(hs.Contains((int)ro["frm"])
    ro["tag"] = ro["frm"];
}
```

If your array is a string and your table is a string:

```
var hs = (new string[]{"1","2","3","4","5"}).ToHashSet();

foreach(DataRow ro in dataTable.Rows){
  if(hs.Contains((string)ro["frm"])
    ro["tag"] = ro["frm"];
}
```

If your table is an int and your array is a string:

```
var hs = (new string[]{"1","2","3","4","5"}).Select(int.Parse).ToHashSet();

foreach(DataRow ro in dataTable.Rows){
  if(hs.Contains((int)ro["frm"])
    ro["tag"] = ro["frm"];
}
```

Comment: sorry my data is in string array and it is duplicate in nature and row count is 20 and my data table contain 67 records also duplicate in nature kindly  help me to sort this issue i am stuck in this this is the link structure               https://drive.google.com/file/d/12kPEaWrVVw_LKgvdOTMD-On30MAvSSeY/view?usp=sharing      when i use    DataRow[] drFound= dtItems.Select("frm=" + item); it does not return any row i dont know why

Comment: But, I didn't tell you to do that.. I said to use a hash set, and do every row.. There is no difference between using array and list, for converting to hashset.. only the string bit causes a problem. Whether you should convert it to int depends on if the data in the table is int or string. If table is string, leave the list as a string. If table is an int, convert the list/array to int, then put to hashset. I made some edits